# CheckBox to switch interior color of all cells

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I want to make a macro that switch the backgroung color of all cells with a specific color RGB(252, 252, 250) to another color RGB(217, 217, 217) in entire workbook

Comment: all cells? so it might be anywhere within the 65K*256 cells?

Comment: Use ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this macro,

```
Sub colorSwitch()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
For j = 1 To Columns.Count
    If Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(252, 252, 250) Then
        Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

But this would take a while to execute as it loops through all cells in the sheet. It would be better if you have a short range, which you can provide with the `i` and `j` variant for the macro to execute faster.

Comment: Will this still work if his cells are red due to conditional formatting? If that's the case, he might need `.DisplayFormat`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541950/get-a-background-color-with-vba-excel-function this might help. But OP did not tell anything about conditional formatting

Comment: I'm saying if the cells are red due to conditional formatting, no, this would not satisfy the IF condition. Because he didn't say whether or not they're red due to that I thought I'd just add that :)

Comment: Can you give me an example of range I can provide for I and J?

Comment: @dwirony `.DisplayFormat` can't be changed, but the conditional formatting color can.

Comment: @MaxBridge it depends on your sheet's data range. If you have just 10 rows and 5 columns with data, give 10 and 5 respectively

Answer (score 0):

You can Record Macro of [Replace Format](http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/04/04/change-cell-formats-with-find-replace-in-excel/):

```
Application.FindFormat.Clear
Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(252, 252, 250)
Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear
Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)

Cells.Replace "", "", SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
```